# "Server not found" after updating DNS nameservers during site move

Tags: wordpress, dns, godaddy, nameserver

Some acquaintances of mine inherited a website running a custom wordpress template and the previous owner asked them to take over and to get it set up on their own server.  I was asked to assist since I was the only one they knew with some technical skills.

The previous site owner send me a backup of the web files and the mySQL database and recommended using site5.com for hosting.

I got the files installed, things seemed to be OK and we were then ready to transfer the DNS.

The domain is registered through GoDaddy and the prior owner issued a transfer to me, I got signed up accepted the domain and then went in and set the nameservers per site5 instructions:  dns.site5.com and dns2.site5.com

I expected that this was all that would be required and would just wait for the dns entries to update.

However, at present when I browse or ping the Website.  I get Server not Found.

Is there anything else that I should have done or am I just in DNS Limbo?

WHOIS.NET reports that it is registered to me and has the nameservers correct.

You'll have to excuse me, while I've set up several websites internally at my work, this is the first time I've worked on an internet website.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you see your site on site5.com's IP address? Did they give you a temporary url so that you can test it prior to the nameserver change?

Have site5/you setup your account so that there are records pointing to your site? If you haven't transferred the domain in to site5 or set up the domain in their "backstage" their nameservers won't know about your site.

Could you give us the url so we can have a look?

Comment: This was the issue.  When they got around to answering my ticket, they had to propagate something or other. and now it working.

Answer (score 1):

Make sure you have an A record with the IP of the server hosting the files in GoDaddy domain management. Also, on your server, be sure your httpd.conf has the site's entry, maybe in the virtual hosts section (if you're using apache).